# In Eclipse what is the difference between "Open Type"/"Open Resource"?

Tags: eclipse

Can any one please tell me the difference of "Open Type" (Ctrl + Shift + T) and "Open Resource" (Ctrl + Shift + R) in eclipse.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

"Open Type" lets you open any class, interface, or other compiled module no matter where it is located.  ["Open Resource"](http://greatwebguy.com/programming/eclipse/eclipse-open-resource-shortcut-ctrlshiftr/) does the same thing for non-classes, etc (things like config files, images, etc).

Basically, both commands let you find different files quickly without having to search through the tree and directory structure.

Comment: Hi jason,

      Thankyou very much for ur assistance its helps me a lot to which scenario i shoukd opt for.


Thanks..

 Ragav.K

Comment: you should set the answer as accepted if it is really helped you

Comment: I think "open resource" part is not 100% correct. With open resource, you can find also classes in the project (not in dependencies)

Comment: @jasCav   why do we need two different things like type and resource, why i am asking this question is, because open resource option can open java files as well as resources.

Answer (score 9):

Types are language-related such as classes (and usually in the include paths), Resources are simply just files.

Comment: Hi yclian,

      Thankyou very much for ur assistance its helps me a lot to which scenario i shoukd opt for.


Thanks..

 Ragav.K

Comment: So in your words, resources search should take more time than type search ?

Comment: @EnsomHodder: Not necessarily. That actually depends upon the searching algo Eclipse uses. Honestly, we need not bother about it. I never felt any difference as such and it's pretty fast, the results actually change dynamically as you type the search keywords.